# Closing a programmatically created Logback DBAppender

Tags: java, logging, logback

We programmatically created in our project Logback `DBAppender`:

```
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
    DBAppender dbAppender = new DBAppender();

    DataSourceConnectionSource connectionSource = new DataSourceConnectionSource();
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        cpds.setJdbcUrl(dbConfig.getJdbcUrl());
        cpds.setUser(dbConfig.getUserID());
        cpds.setPassword(dbConfig.getPassword());
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        Logs.error("Unable to set driver class. PropertyVetoException: " + e);
    }

    connectionSource.setDataSource(cpds);
    connectionSource.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
    connectionSource.start();

    dbAppender.setConnectionSource(connectionSource);
    dbAppender.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
    dbAppender.start();

    logger.addAppender(dbAppender);
```

So, I have a question - do I need to close that connection source when i will stop application?

Something like:

```
  connectionSource.stop();
  dbAppender.stop();
```

And one more question. If I have several loggers - can I create one `DBAppender` for all of them? Cause I noticed that we need to add to dbAppender and connectionSource context, like:

```
 connectionSource.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
 dbAppender.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
```

Is that context same for all loggers and I need to add that only from one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Logback v 1.1.0 all connections opened by `DBAppender` are closed on your behalf. So, as long as you are using a version of Logback >= 1.1.0 you do not have to explicitly close any connections opened by the  `DBAppender`.

Re this:

> If I have several loggers - can i create one dpappender for all of them? Cause i noticed that we need to add to dbAppender and connectionSource context, like ...

You do not have to invoke these lines for each logger ...

```
connectionSource.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
dbAppender.setContext(logger.getLoggerContext());
```

... since each logger shares the same `LoggerContext` so you should only invoke the above lines once.

Comment: We are using logback version 1.2.3, but through slf4j v1.7.25. So in that case i still do not have to close connection source and dbappender?

Comment: Logback v 1.2.3 > Logback v 1.1.0 so I think you're ok, no need to explicitly close the connection(s).